# Why is an on "click, "button" being handled by a span instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I'm experiencing something that seems quite wrong with events and `jquery`.

I have the following simple HTML list

```
<ul>
  <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button> Chocolate</li>
  <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button> Butter</li>
  <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button> Milk</li>
  <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button> ugar</li>
</ul>
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(evt) {
  console.debug("got a click in", evt.target);
});
```

When I click in a button I get

```
got a click in <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>
```

and not in the button.

Why?

Comment: You could also use the `currentTarget` property of the `event` object.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  `this` and `evt.currentTarget` are not the same object.

Comment: Your button text is a span (see the html of your buttons). This means that when a user clicks on the button, they are really clicking on the inner span. JavaScript automatically bubbles the event up to the containing elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` property of event objects points to the originator of the event; here, it’s the element that was the first target of the click, and that was apparently the `<span>`.

If you want the element selected by `.on()`, jQuery provides it as `this`.

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(evt) {
    console.debug("got a click in", this);
});
```

(Note that you don’t have to wait for `$(document).ready` when using delegation rooted in `document`.)

Answer (score 0):

Any element can receive a click event. If it doesn't handle it the event will "bubble up" through parent elements.